Problem doing backup to OneDrive of iPhone "low quality / optimized" photos
I haven't done a backup of my iPhone photos to OneDrive in 10 months, and now I realize that my iPhone 13 photos, which have been optimized by iCloud, can't be uploaded to OneDrive. In order to do it OneDrive requires the high res version of the photos, so I have to find a way to download the high res version of my photos to my iPhone, but I would like to choose only the 2024 photos or I will not have enough space on my iPhone if I de-select the optimize button on the iPhone photos. I could select and view one photo by one, but it will take ages.
Any idea on how to solve this problem?

If you're storing them in OneDrive, why are you also storing them in iCloud?  iCloud Photo Library isn't a backup, so kudos on making a backup, but why go through iCloud at all?
